# How to draw a Highcharts tree map where sum of children values are not equal to parent value

Tags: highcharts, treemap

In a highcharts tree map I know the value of the parent and the values of some children - not of all children.

```
data:[{ id: 'C1', parent: 'P', value: 25, color: 'blue'},
  { id: 'C2', parent: 'P', value: 35, color: 'yellow'},
  { id: 'P', value: 100, color: 'red'}]
```

As you can see, there are missing children with a sum of 40.

When I draw this chart, I get P with an area of 100, but the children get enlared to 42 and 58, so they fill the complete area of P. If I omit the value in P, the children are sized correctly, but P has only a size of 60.

The wished result would be P with a size of 100 , and the children with 25 and 35, leaving 40 free (shown red).

The only way I could manage this was some dummy C3 child with the  value of (P-C1-C2), but I would prefer not to do this calculation.

Is there a setting I can use? ignoreHiddenPoint: true did not help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for that would be to add a hidden point (child), since the tree map calculates the children and accumulates these values at parent.

```js
let Data = [{
    id: 'C1',
    parent: 'P',
    value: 25,
    color: 'blue'
  },
  {
    id: 'C2',
    parent: 'P',
    value: 35,
    color: 'yellow'
  },
      {
    id: 'C3',
    parent: 'P',
    value: 40,
    color: 'transparent',
  },
  {
    id: 'P',
    value: null,
    color: 'red'
  }
]


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    opacity: 1,
    type: 'treemap',
    layoutAlgorithm: 'strip',
    allowDrillToNode: true,
    animationLimit: 1000,
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    levelIsConstant: true,
    levels: [{
      level: 1,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      },
      borderWidth: 3
    }],
    data: Data
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/treemap.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g81L4xfp/